# Cannot establish a connection to h2 database in netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, h2

i have an embedded h2 database with .mv.db extension. I added the latest h2 driver h2 1.4.189 but i still get this exception when testing connection

```
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:h2:E:\xxx using org.h2.Driver (General error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vividsolutions/jts/io/ParseException" [50000-189])
```

How can i solve ?

Comment: you need to add the jar to your project that contains the class that is not found. if you use maven, add the dependency. use the web or the netbeans internal maven dependency search function ("Add dependency") to find out which jar/dependency you need to add.

Comment: ok . but there is no project. i'm just trying to use the netbeans to open database and see it with its interface.i get the exact same error/exception with DbVisualizer

Comment: I tried the driver in Netbeans and it worked for me. Can you check View -> IDE Log to see if there is a longer version of the exception stack trace with a cause listed? You might try pasting it into http://www.h2database.com/html/sourceError.html